# Merge wrongly spelled [thumbail] tag into [thumbnail]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

There's a tag [thumbail](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/thumbail) which is obviously a misspelling of [thumbnail](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/thumbnail). Can one of the ♦ moderators merge the tags? Alternatively, since it's only five questions, can somebody with edit privileges apply the correct tag on those questions?

Comment: Done....,,,,,,,

Comment: Thanks! I guess it's [tag:status-completed] then :)